# Excel Dynamic Array Function to Sum Repeated Numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I have the following data in Excel:

[image: spreadsheet 1]

The real data will go on for over 100 columns.

What I want to get is a sum of the number if it were to repeat horizontally by the number of repeats. **NB**: Technically I'm repeating one less time, but I'm not wanted to split hairs.

Here's what the expansion would look like if I were to create multiple rows:

[image: spreadsheet 2]

I then can just sum those rows:

[image: spreadsheet 3]

What I'd like is a dynamic array function that lets me sum the values without the intermediate rows. It's doing my head in.

Here's what I'd like it to look like:

[image: spreadsheet 4]

I've tried to start with `=BYCOL(R12C23:R12C,lambda(x,` but am totally stuck at how to compute the result.

Can anyone suggest how to complete the formula or offer an alternative?

Comment: What a nice question! It shouldn't be too bad to create the 2D array using reduce/hstack for each row then reduce/vstack to stack them and finally get the column totals. The challenge for me is that you shouldn't have to actually create the 2D array...there should be a more direct way of creating the column totals just in a 1D array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option:

[image]

Formula in `B3`:

```
=LET(x,B2:E2,y,COLUMN(x),z,TOCOL(y),TOROW(BYROW((z<=y+x-1)*(z>=y)*B1:E1,SUM)))
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly the type of solution I was working towards.

Comment: @TomSharpe, let me know what you come up with! I feel this is still very verbose.

Comment: @JvdV - Thank you for this. I'm getting a `#NAME?` error. `=LET(x,R13C23:R13C26,y,COLUMN(x),z,TOCOL(y),TOROW(BYROW((z<=y+x-1)*(z>=y)*R12C23:R12C26,SUM)))`

Comment: @Enigmativity, I've used the ETA LAMBDA syntax where we could skip over the `LAMBDA(r,SUM(r))` part and sum directly. You might want to fiddle that back in to see if that resolves the error. Furthermore, please note that I deduct 1 in my formula due to the fact there is one column to the left of the start of the array. Adjust your formula accordingly.

Comment: It works for me. I will give it bit more thought but doubt I will come up with anything shorter TBH !

Comment: It works when I use `LAMBDA(r,SUM(r))`. Thank you.

Comment: Genius! What did you mean by *"deduct -1"* you mentioned in a comment? It works anywhere i.e. you could use `SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(x))` instead of `COLUMN(x)`.

Comment: @VBasic2008, yeah that's right!

Comment: Can I trouble you to see if you can convert this to a single cell result that doesn't spill? I need it to work from the current cell to the left.

Comment: @Enigmativity just add the '@' operator for implicit intersection to return the first value in an otherwise spilled array of values.

Comment: @JvdV - It's not the first value I need. It's the last one.

Comment: Ahh, then nest the formula in `TAKE(......,-1)`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=MMULT(B1:E1,LET(n,COLUMNS(B1:E1),x,SEQUENCE(n,,0,-1)+SEQUENCE(,n),(x>=0 )*(x<=TRANSPOSE(B2:E2))))
```

or:

```
=MAP(COLUMN(B1:E1)-1,LAMBDA(x,SUM(TAKE($B1:E1*(SEQUENCE(,x,x,-1)<=B2:E2),,x))))
```

[image]

Comment: Can I trouble you to see if you can convert this to a single cell result that doesn't spill? I need it to work from the current cell to the left.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had chance to sit down and work through this properly but my idea (very similar to @JvdV and @Dang D. Khanh) was just to work across a single row including all the values that were within range for each column:

```
=LET(values,B1:E1,repeats,B2:E2,seq,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(values)),
MAP(seq,LAMBDA(c,SUM(values*(c>=seq)*(c<seq+repeats)))))
```

[image]

---

The equivalent formula for displaying one cell at a time would be:

```
=LET(values,$B$1:$E$1,repeats,$B$2:$E$2,seq,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(values)),col,COLUMN()-1,
SUM(values*(col>=seq)*(col<seq+repeats)))
```

or to show result for the column to the left of the current cell:

```
=LET(values,$B$1:$E$1,repeats,$B$2:$E$2,seq,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(values)),col,COLUMN()-2,
SUM(values*(col>=seq)*(col<seq+repeats)))
```

However I don't like the mix of column numbers and sequence running from 1 to 4 because it would only work if starting in column B.

Maybe better to use column numbers only like this:

```
=LET(values,$B$1:$E$1,repeats,$B$2:$E$2,seq,COLUMN(values),col,COLUMN(),
SUM(values*(col>=seq)*(col<seq+repeats)))
```

and

```
=LET(values,$B$1:$E$1,repeats,$B$2:$E$2,seq,COLUMN(values),col,COLUMN()-1,
SUM(values*(col>=seq)*(col<seq+repeats)))
```

which are not vulnerable to insertion/deletion of columns to the left of the data.

Comment: Can I trouble you to see if you can convert this to a single cell result that doesn't spill? I need it to work from the current cell to the left.